# invalid Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently getting a 'invalid column name' isssue, as shown in the picture below, when there is a column named 'MDL_ID in the table 'Firearms'

Any help in regards to why I am getting this?

[image]

Comment: you just haven't refreshed intellisense. You can force a refresh using ctrl+shift+r

Comment: You need a `GO` between adding the column and using it.

Comment: Also be aware that inserting into the table will make all new records. This will **not** add values to MDL_ID column for current records in the table.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, thanks, i used merge statements for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh the Database !!!

If needed you can also Logout and Login the SQL Server.